Unknown "nil" backend with org-export-dispatch for beamer
I'm trying to use a single org-mode file to make a single org file that is exported to  multiple slide-deck pdf files using beamer. I've got each tree labelled with a unique #+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: foo.pdf
When I export the entire org file to a pdf using org-beamer-export-to-pdf, the pdf file exports just fine.
However, if I try to use org-export-dispatch C-s l P to export a single subtree using Beamer, I get the following error:
Unknown "nil" backend: Aborting export

Error: error ("Unknown \"nil\" backend: Aborting export")
  mapbacktrace(#f(compiled-function (evald func args flags) #<bytecode -0xdd7af0c8c512f81>))
  debug-early-backtrace()
  debug-early(error (error "Unknown \"nil\" backend: Aborting export"))
  error("Unknown \"%s\" backend: Aborting export" nil)
  org-export-barf-if-invalid-backend(nil)
  #<subr org-export-as>(beamer t nil nil (:output-file "slides.tex"))
  apply(#<subr org-export-as> (beamer t nil nil (:output-file "slides.tex")))
  (let ((old-async-init-file org-export-async-init-file) (org-export-async-init-file (make-temp-file "doom-org-async-export"))) (doom-file-write org-export-async-init-file (list (list 'setq 'org-export-async-debug (or org-export-async-debug debug-on-error) 'load-path (list 'quote load-path)) (cons 'unwind-protect (cons (list 'let (list (list 'init-file old-async-init-file)) (cons 'if (cons 'init-file (cons '(load init-file nil t) (cons (cons 'load (cons early-init-file '(nil t))) '((require 'doom-start))))))) '((delete-file load-file-name)))))) (apply fn args))
  +org--fix-async-export-a(#<subr org-export-as> beamer t nil nil (:output-file "slides.tex"))
  apply(+org--fix-async-export-a #<subr org-export-as> (beamer t nil nil (:output-file "slides.tex")))
  org-export-as(beamer t nil nil (:output-file "slides.tex"))
  (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex"))
  (print (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex")))
  (progn nil (progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (setq org-babel-confirm-evaluate-answer-no t)) (require 'ox) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x11e2802acb44c4e4>)) (restore-buffer-modified-p nil) (print (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex"))))
  (unwind-protect (progn nil (progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (setq org-babel-confirm-evaluate-answer-no t)) (require 'ox) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x11e2802acb44c4e4>)) (restore-buffer-modified-p nil) (print (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex")))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn nil (progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (setq org-babel-confirm-evaluate-answer-no t)) (require 'ox) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x11e2802acb44c4e4>)) (restore-buffer-modified-p nil) (print (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex")))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
  (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn nil (progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (setq org-babel-confirm-evaluate-answer-no t)) (require 'ox) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x11e2802acb44c4e4>)) (restore-buffer-modified-p nil) (print (let ((output (org-export-as 'beamer t nil nil '(:output-file "slides.tex")))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert output) (if (bolp) nil (insert "\n")) (let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)) (write-region nil nil "slides.tex"))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) (or (condition-case nil (progn (funcall 'nil "slides.tex")) (error nil)) "slides.tex")))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))))
  load-with-code-conversion("/private/var/folders/b6/mf5gf7dj1nd_99ntp16zl6gw0000gn/T/org-export-processwkfeST" "/private/var/folders/b6/mf5gf7dj1nd_99ntp16zl6gw0000gn/T/org-export-processwkfeST" nil t)
  command-line-1(("-l" "/var/folders/b6/mf5gf7dj1nd_99ntp16zl6gw0000gn/T/doom-org-async-exportjRuyQ7" "-l" "/var/folders/b6/mf5gf7dj1nd_99ntp16zl6gw0000gn/T/org-export-processwkfeST"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()

I'm wondering:

Is there a better way to export a single sub-tree to a Beamer slide deck, and/or to export all sub-trees to the pdf files as given by #+EXPORT_FILE_NAME?
If not, is there a way to debug the above error to find out what is nil and causing the above problems?

My org file starts like this:
#+subtitle: Foo
#+AUTHOR: me
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [dvipsnames]
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil H:2 num:t
#+LATEX_CMD: xelatex
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex

#+latex_header: \usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson} %% Option 'sfdefault' if the base

#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col)
#+beamer: \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

#+latex_header: \mode<beamer>{\usetheme{metropolis}}


Unrelated to your question, but I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. This can lead to missing texts in overlays and notes. If you need unicode support, use lualatex instead. That's also much more powerful. Otherwise use pdflatex, that's much faster.

Also I would no longer use the metropolis theme. It is partially incompatible with current beamer/latex and only held together by a lot of duck tape. Instead use the moloch theme, an updated fork of metropolis.

Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz there is no tex file, it fails before generating one.

Try C-c C-e C-s l b to see if you get a TeX file. Post any backtrace you get that way if it's any different from the above (probably not). FWIW, that works for me (up to getting the TeX file - I haven't tried to produce a PDF).

What is +org--fix-async-export-a? I don't have that in my setup at all. Are you trying to export with async on? If so, turn it off and try again.

@NickD Indeed that was the culprit, it exports fine with async turned off. Good catch! Doing describe-function seems to show that it's part of org.el, but things with the + prefix are often part of Doom emacs, so maybe it's a doom specific patch?

Async export starts up a new emacs to run the async process and requires some initialization in order to work. Do C-h i g(org) RET i async RET to read how async works and C-h v org-async-init-file to see how async init works.

There is a call to doom-file-write in the backtrace: it seems to write its own async init file (including a (require 'doom-start) which probably brings doom into the new emacs, complicating even more a process which is complicated enough already.)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - you say "[xelatex usage with beamer]  can lead to missing texts in overlays and notes." - can you provide a pointer to the details? Thanks in advance!

@NickD See e.g. https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337
